# Have I thought the correct way on this calculus problem?

Tags: calculus

> Assume that $I_{1}<I_{2}$ for two real numbers $I_{i}$, $i = 1,2$ and assume that for all partitions $P$ of the interval $[a,b]$, $L(f,P) \leq I_{1}<I_{2} \leq U(f,P)$: where $L(f,P)$ is the undersum to the function $f$ as determined by the partition $P$, and $U(f,P)$ is the corresponding oversum. If so, what is $\int_a^b f(x)dx$?

The way I have tried to solve this is that I know that $a$ is less than $b$ if I understand the question correct. There for the answer simply should be, $\int_a^b f(x)dx = U(f,P) - L(f,P)$. But this is not that much of a proof eaven if it is correct. Can some one please explain it to me?

Comment: I think in this case $\int_a^b f(x) dx$ does not exist in the Riemann sense, because the lower integral is at most $I_1$ while the upper integral is at least $I_2$.

Comment: Ok, but if the two partitions are never equal, does not that mean that we must be able to express it as a function some how?

Comment: Can you elaborate? I don't understand your question.

Comment: Expanding a bit: the formalism of the Darboux integral goes like this. Define the lower and upper sums, then the lower integral is the supremum of the lower sums over all partitions, and the upper integral is the infimum of the upper sums over all partitions. The function is Darboux integrable if the lower and upper integrals are the same, in which case the Darboux integral is their common value.

Comment: (Cont.) It is a theorem (proven in any undergraduate level real analysis text) that the Riemann integral and the Darboux integral are exactly equivalent: they integrate the same functions and assign the same values to the integrals.

Comment: Ahh yes finally got it I hope! Sorry I started to read in my book and that is why I did not answer. Basicly it is becaus the uppersum always is larger than the undersum, because of this the exact value does not exist, because the undersum and uppersum never can be the same? Have I understood it correctly?

Comment: Technically it is OK if the upper sum is always larger than the lower sum, but here it is always larger than the upper sum *by at least a fixed amount* (namely $I_2-I_1$), which is where the problem arises. For some intuition, notice that $\sup \, (0,1) = \inf \, (1,2)$ even though these two sets are disjoint.